# MongoDB PHP, insert() not working

Tags: php, mongodb, insert

I'm trying to set up a simple MongoDB and insert some data. I have to use PHP and I am running the code on external server owned by my uniersity (it is obligatory for me, the server has everything set up). My problem is that I'm using code from tutorialsPoint and everything works great until it reaches 'insert' function. Then something happens and it will not echo anything beyond insert(). I have no idea what to do, and why this happens. Any suggestions?

code:

```
<?php
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();
   echo "Connection to database successfully";

   // select a database
   $db = $m->mydb;
   echo "Database mydb selected";
   $collection = $db->mycol;
   echo "Collection selected succsessfully";

   $document = array( 
      "title" => "MongoDB", 
      "description" => "database", 
      "likes" => 100,
      "url" => "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/",
      "by", "tutorials point"
   );

   $collection->insert($document);
   echo "Document inserted successfully";
?>
```

Comment: Then read error logs.

Comment: OK, I've got it. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You array does have an error.

You used: `"by", "tutorials point"`

use this:

```
"by"=> "tutorials point"
```

Hope this will solve the problem.